Cabal upload package fails with Encountered missing or private dependency
I'm trying to upload my first Haskell package:
$ git clone https://github.com/OrenGitHub/dhscanner.ast.git 2>/dev/null
$ cd dhscanner.ast/
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.10.1.0 # <--- modern enough, right ?
compiled using version 3.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
$ cabal update # <--- just to be on the safe side
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Package list of hackage.haskell.org is up to date.
The index-state is set to 2024-07-23T00:03:37Z.

When I google-d the error message, cabal new-build was recommended
$ cabal new-build
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.4.7 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0 (lib) (first run)
Configuring library for dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0..
Building library for dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 3] Compiling Location         ( ... )
[2 of 3] Compiling Token            ( ... )
[3 of 3] Compiling Ast              ( ... )
$ cabal install --force-reinstalls --lib
Wrote tarball sdist to
/home/oren/GitHub/dhscanner.ast/dist-newstyle/sdist/dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0.tar.gz
< ... omitted for brevity ...>

But it didn't help, and I still can't upload my package:
$ cabal upload -d --publish -u ***** -p ********
No documentation tarball specified. Building a documentation tarball with
default settings...
If you need to customise Haddock options, run 'haddock --for-hackage' first to
generate a documentation tarball.
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: aeson (dependency of dhscanner-ast)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: aeson, dhscanner-ast)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: dhscanner-ast, aeson
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0...
Error: cabal: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
aeson <2.3

EDIT1:
$ cabal info aeson
* aeson            (library)
    Synopsis:      Fast JSON parsing and encoding
    Versions available: 1.5.5.1, 1.5.6.0, 2.0.3.0, 2.1.1.0, 2.1.2.0, 2.1.2.1,
                        2.2.1.0, 2.2.2.0, 2.2.3.0 (and 89 others)
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ] # <--- that's weird, right?

also, cabal haddock finishes fine, with resulting html files.

1 requested in comments

That's an odd one for sure. Do you get the same error from cabal haddock? I don't really want to try running cabal upload locally to test things, and it doesn't seem to have a --dry-run-alike. What does cabal info aeson say?

@DanielWagner I added the commands to the question - so the aeson does not seem to be installed, but cabal build succeeds - not sure what's going on ...

[ Not installed ] is fine and normal. Nix-style (aka new-style) builds create build artifacts in a location known to cabal, but not to GHC, and only things know to GHC are considered "installed".  I suspect this is a bug -- e.g. perhaps cabal upload -d is going via old-style haddock or something. I would recommend trying new-style haddock (i.e. cabal haddock); if that works, you can upload the tarball that creates by appending it to your cabal upload -d command rather than trying to create and upload all in one command. Also if that works, file a bug on the cabal issue tracker.

So indeed, the doc gen interfered - because when I remove the -d, I get to an authorization error ( contact the Hackage trustees ). I'll post a bug.

Just to be clear: if you remove the -d, you're doing a different action. Without -d, you're uploading a package; with -d you're uploading documentation. They're two separate things, and if you want both things uploaded, you have to call cabal twice. Does that make sense? Rereading your question now it seems to me you may not have realized that -d isn't "upload both", it's "only upload documentation".

Oh I see. Yes, you're right - I thought it's "upload both". So now I'm doing the package uploading which involves the Hackage trustees - once it's working, I'll do the doc upload. Thanks !


I posted the problem in cabal/issues,
and got an answer from contributor GitHub/ulysses4ever.
Writing the answer here too, in case future cabal users will run into similar difficulties.
It turns out the documentation tar has to already exist before we can cabal upload it.
Also, the package itself must be uploaded before the documentation.

$ cabal haddock --haddock-for-hackage --haddock-option=--hyperlinked-source
# < ... omitted for brevity ... >
Documentation tarball created:
C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\dhscanner.ast\dist-newstyle\dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.1-docs.tar.gz
$ cabal upload --publish C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\dhscanner.ast\dist-newstyle\sdist\dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0.tar.gz # the package comes *before* the documentation
$ cabal upload --publish -d C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\dhscanner.ast\dist-newstyle\dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0-docs.tar.gz

